# Is there a way to squash a commits in already merged pull request?

Tags: git, github, merge

Consider this scenario:

1. I am working on my local feature or defect branch which is created
   from develop branch.
2. Then I released my changes as multiple commits
   to my remote branch (as it happens in the PR review process).
3. My PR is finally approved by team reviewing my changes. But I forgot to
   quash all my commits on my remote and local branch and merged my
   remote branch in to develop branch.
4. Deleted the local and remote branch.

Now I realized that I merged my changes in to develop without doing a squash.

**So is there way for me to squash my commits in to develop branch after the fact that all my commits were merged in develop branch ?**

Comment: you can revert, and then cherry pick each commit into a new branch, and squash there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Option 1: Squash the commits on your remote `develop` branch.

Option 2: Since you merged your `feature-branch` before deleting it, you should still have access to all those commits.  You could `git revert` on your `develop` branch back to the commit right before your merge commit.  Then checkout the last commit you did on your `feature-branch` with `git checkout <commit reference>`.  Run `git rebase -i` to squash the commits before you merge the `feature-branch` back into `master`.